# null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint Django

Tags: python, django, psql

I know there are a lot of solutions for this problem but they seem a bit different than mine. Here is my models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import HStoreField
# Create your models here.

class Events(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    start = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    end = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

Very simple table and I want the primary key in `Auth_user` to be the foreign key in my `Events` table. So of course this would mean that a `User` has to be logged in and authenticated for this to work. In my views.py I have:

```
def createEvent(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.user
        print (user)        # Check for Authentication
        name = request.POST['name']
        start = request.POST['start']
        end = request.POST['end']
        Events.objects.create(
            name = name,
            start = start,
            end =end,
        )
```

The print statement will print out the current user logged in. I can confirm that this part does show that a user is logged in and that this user is in the `auth_user` table with a unique `id`. However, when I try to submit a form, I get a null value for the `user` column. Any ideas?

Comment: `Events.objects.create(name = name, start = start, end =end)` The user isn't being set anywhere...On a separate note, you should use a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/) for something like this, will save a lot of work.

Comment: @jens, that should probably have been an answer. Also tell the op how to do proper is_authenticated check.

Comment: Wait sorry, shouldn't the user already bet set in the models.py? `user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)`

Comment: That says Event should have a field containing a user - you need to define what the value should be though in each Event. Models define the table in your database, when you do `Event.objects.create` you're creating a new row in that table - if that helps...

Comment: Thanks I had a misunderstanding but now I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making what you have right now *work*:

```
def createEvent(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.user
        print (user)        # Check for Authentication
        name = request.POST['name']
        start = request.POST['start']
        end = request.POST['end']
        # The user has to be included before being saved
        Events.objects.create(name=name, start=start, end=end, user=user)
```

Some better practices:
Using a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/) (note there are [class based generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms) that make this easier too), and the [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) decorator

```
# forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Event

class EventForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('user', 'start', 'end', 'name')

# views.py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def create_event(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = EventForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = EventForm()
        return render(..., {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thank you, I am actually aware of the model Form. However, for this purpose I am using Jquery's Modal Form. So I am using ajax to send the data over.

Comment: I'd caution against ditching Django Forms to use javascript - you don't have to decide between one or the other (I went down that road, it gets messy), they can play together. For example, in your case, you can render the form manually but in your view pass the request.POST to the form instance for validation (it also turns all values into Python objects for you).

Answer (score 0):

Just add the user instance because it's required by `Events`.  I think you should use `DateField` or `DateTimeField` on start and end field.  Not sure but I think you plan to put a date value there.

```
Events.objects.create(user=request.user, name=name, start=start, end=end)
```

You should also add a `@login_required` for your function.

Comment: Actually, I have a middleware provided for that `login_required` part so I don't have to put that everywhere.

Comment: Ok.  you can just assign `request.user`

Answer (score 0):

My solution is this:

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    user = request.user
    user_id = User.objects.get(username=user).pk
    name = request.POST['name']
    start = request.POST['start']
    end = request.POST['end']
    Events.objects.create(
        user_id=user_id,
        name = name,
        start = start,
        end =end,
    )
```

Is that an alright solution? Could there be something better?

Comment: change user_id to user.  request.user already return a `User` object, no need another query `user_id = User.objects.get(username=user).pk`